# Set Permanent Flutter Path

Tags: flutter

The steps for modifying this variable permanently for all terminal sessions are machine-specific. Typically you add a line to a file that is executed whenever you open a new window. For example:

1. Determine the directory where you placed the Flutter SDK. You will need this in Step 3.
2. Open (or create) $HOME/.bash_profile. The file path and filename might be different on your machine.
3. Add the following line and change [PATH_TO_FLUTTER_GIT_DIRECTORY] to be the path where you cloned Flutter’s git repo:

$ export PATH="$PATH:[PATH_TO_FLUTTER_GIT_DIRECTORY]/flutter/bin"

4. Run source $HOME/.bash_profile to refresh the current window.
5. Verify that the flutter/bin directory is now in your PATH by running:

echo $PATH

Comment: You may find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74337608/6921031

Answer (score 0):

In mac, you should add it as follows in ".zshrc":

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/matteo/Documents/flutter/bin"
```

After you have updated the ".zshrc" file, run this command to ensure changes have been notified to OS

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Reference: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos

A similar concept is for Linux system using bash files

Answer (score -1):

I tried a lot of methods but this one permanent solution worked for me like a charm:

1. open Terminal in your Mac: type: 
      sudo nano /echo/paths
2. Add the code to the file: 
      /users/yourUserName/flutter/bin
3. Save the file using Control+X and Press Y and Enter

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: to help people understand the problem if they are having any trouble resolving the issue

Comment: i tried a lot of methods, this worked for me. so i thought of sharing it @pskink

Comment: problem to set the permanent file path in flutter. in flutter documentation, its not understandable clearly. so this is the alternate method